# Is there a way to uninstall Wix bundle from CMD

Tags: wix

I have a Wix Bundle which installs one MSI. Now I want to uninstall the Bundle automatically.

I have tried msiexec /x which only uninstalled the MSI and wmic which could not find the Bundle.

Is there a way to uninstall Wix bundle automatically ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run the original bundle.exe with the `-uninstall` switch. You can also specify `-quiet` or `-passive` to get less UI.

Comment: You can also find the .exe to run via the registry - there's an UninstallString entry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{GUID} that contains the command to run to uninstall it - the bundle exe gets cached in ProgramData.

Comment: @BCran Where can I find the GUID(under Uninstall key) of the bundle without installing it? I want to uninstall quietly some broken bundles previously released(not major-upgradable).

Comment: @BCran isn't the UninstallString typically a msiexec that uninstalls the msi only and not the uninstall of bundle?

Answer (score 3):

As the bundle is a standard exe you need to actually run that with the uninstall command-line parameter:

```
C:\BundleName.exe -uninstall
```