# Removing bundle setup (wix) from ARP using CMD

Tags: wix, cmd, bundle, arp

I have an additional question to this qwuestion:

[Is there a way to uninstall Wix bundle from CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530012/is-there-a-way-to-uninstall-wix-bundle-from-cmd)

My bundle installs a msi I've created. When I uninstall this msi using msiexec /uninstall (which can happen when anything in the relation bundle<>msi has been broken for any reason), it is properly deinstalled, but the bundle entry remains in the ARP. Is there a possibility to force that bundle to be removed from arp? When using the switches you mentioned, Rob, still my ui pops up, checking for its msi, detecting thats it's missing and offers me an install. I simply would love the bundle entry in ARP to vanish ;-)

Or do I have to handle it in my bootstrapper itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSI has no knowledge of the Bundle. To remove the Bundle, you can do as the linked question suggests: `bundle.exe -uninstall -quiet`.

Comment: I have to handle those params on my own in the bundle.exe, right? At the moment we use our own param internally.