# I would like to uninstall BUNDLE via CMD or C# code WITHOUT original bundle.exe

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn, wix3

I have seen other posts

[Is there a way to uninstall Wix bundle from CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530012/is-there-a-way-to-uninstall-wix-bundle-from-cmd)

[Removing bundle setup (wix) from ARP using CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620361/removing-bundle-setup-wix-from-arp-using-cmd)

However, in both, the solution suggests to use original bundle.exe to uninstall.

With my requirement, this is not possible. Followings are why it is not possible.

---

I saw [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530012/is-there-a-way-to-uninstall-wix-bundle-from-cmd#comment22623465_15530454) in the first posts that registry

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{xxx...xxx}\InstallSource

contains the directory in ProgramData, I checked that folder, but unfortunately, there was msi but no exe.

I also checked the UninstallString, but that was only having msiexec.exe /i{xxx...xxx}

I can successuflly uninstall the program with `msiexec.exe /x {xxx...xxx}`, and registry entry is gone, but ARP entry still remains for bundle since I did not remove bundle.

---

When I use uninstall from Add / Remove Program using UI, I am able to uninstall this bundle. But I need way to do so without the UI.

There has to be a way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Actually found the answer.

Since my application was 64 bit, my msi was 64 bit. So I assumed bundle was also 64 bit.

However, the bundle was still using 32 bit.

So by searching WOW6432Node instead, I found the exe path under `BundleCachePath`.

And because I have exe path, I was able to uninstall the bundle.

Comment: I assume the reason is that a `setup.exe` can contain both 32 and 64 bit components and it hence needs to be 32-bit in order to be able to launch on both 32 and 64 bit systems.

Comment: That is most likely the case. Wish I thought of that possibility ahead, but I am just glad I found the solution

Comment: Good debugging effort, and I see you have found the WiX mailing list as well. I need to fix some erroneous links to it from my experimental site: https://www.installdude.com. If you visit, try the "Jumpgate". Could help for other things despite the site not being fully functional yet.

Comment: Thanks and Nice! Your insight is amazing and visible throughout SO, so glad you made a knowledge database! Bookmarked and will first check there first!

Comment: Thanks. I hope to make it better sometime soon. There are many missing features, but it does help to find certain things. A bit heavy on the browser - very poor performance on some tablets and such matters.