# Script uninstall Wix Bundle

Tags: wix

I need to be able to uninstall a Wix bundle from a powershell script.  Previously we would call msiexec and pass the Product Id value from the MSI .wsx file and that did the trick.

With a bundle, I don't see an Id value to use for uninstall.  I the uninstall string in the registry and the associated GUID but I cannot determine where that GUID came from.  It appears to be generated internally during the Wix build process.

I cannot use the other method of calling the exe with -uninstall because the exe is no longer available.  reference this question:
[Is there a way to uninstall Wix bundle from CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530012/is-there-a-way-to-uninstall-wix-bundle-from-cmd)